# Error while creating crosstab from a data set

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, machine-learning

I want to cluster two column names customerid (cid) and state:

```
cid = np.array(b.customerID)
state = np.array(b.State)
pd.crosstab(ind, [cid, state], rownames=['cid'], colnames=['state'], dropna = False)
```

When I try to create crosstab in Python its showing me that

> arrays and names must have the same length

Anyone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think convert to numpy array is not necessary and for `colnames` need 2 values:

```
df = pd.crosstab(df.ind, [df.customerID, df.State], 
                 rownames=['ind'], 
                 colnames=['cid','state'], dropna = False)
```

Answer (score 0):

crt=pd.crosstab(b.State,b.customerID,margins=True)